# Is it possible to change the Debug Profile after creating an MVC Core application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a web application running using Docker and Visual Studio 2017.  I am trying to test it independantly of Docker.  I thought all as I would have to do is as follows:

1) Right click on the project and select properties.
2) Select Debug
3) Change Profile (from Docker) and Launch (from Docker) to IIS Express.

However, when I do this Launch changes, however Profile does not i.e. the Pfofile change appears to rollback when I close the Debug window.  Why is this?

This also happens if I create a new MVC Core 2 project and try to change the Profile.

I also notice that if I create a new MVC Core 2 project without Docker support and then add orchestration support at a later date, then the Docker profile does not appear in the Profile drop down.

I have spent the last two hours Googling this and have not found an answer.  I did find this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39629/changing-the-debug-profile-in-aspnet-core-full-fmk.html

Is it possible to change the Debug Profile after you create an MVC Core 2 project?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run independently of Docker from Visual Studio 2017, you can directly select a different launch profile by clicking on the small caret beside the `run Docker` button.

The steps you describe actually sets the launch profiles in the file under `/Properties/launchSettings.json`.

By default an ASP NET Core application with Docker support enabled comes with three profiles:

1. Docker profile
2. Self host
3. IIS

> I also notice that if I create a new MVC Core 2 project without Docker support and then add orchestration support at a later date, then the Docker profile does not appear in the Profile drop down.

Yes, adding a project without Docker support will result in the Docker profile not being created regardless of orchestration being added.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'm not sure how this answers my question.  Why can't I change the debug profile in properties?

Comment: I thought you meant that you were trying to run under another profile.

Changing the Settings of a Profile from the Property/Debug tab should change the `launchSettings.json`. Is that working?